# django-piston : Overriding default serialization in emitters

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-piston

I am currently writing an API for a django project, and using django-piston for this. However, I need to customize the way certain base types are serialized.

More precisely, my models are subclassed from a special `Model` class, which inherits from `django.db.models.base.ModelBase`, but cannot be serialized as regular django models ... Therefore, I would like to override the serializer for all subclasses of this special `Model` class.

I don't know piston well ... I've looked at the code, and the mapping `type->serializer` (for base types) seems to be hard-coded.

Does anybody know if there is a standard way to override it ???

Comment: "my models are subclassed from a special Model class ... but cannot be serialized"  You've made a terrible mistake in creating your "special" Model class.  Stop now before you create more problems for yourself.  You do not need to break Django.  Put things back so that Django works.  Whatever you did to break serialization was a serious and expensive mistake.  Do. Not. Do. That.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! But you should say that to the folks that are developing (or were developing) this library : http://opensource.bolloretelecom.eu/projects/django-ldapdb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... I couldn't have it working, so I took some code that I had written myself some time ago, made it cleaner, it ended-up in a full Python serialization framework [SpitEat](http://github.com/sebpiq/SpitEat). I have begun writing some documentation, but it's a work in progress.

I have given-up using **piston**, since it is not the first time it disappoints me by its lack of flexibility on (de)serialization operations.

**SpitEat** aims to be fully customizable, (by seeing serialization from a more abstract point of view than just "django objects") and provides serializers for Django, tested, but not so well documented yet, and with features that are still missing (again it is a work in progress).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the serialization yourself. The handlers only expect and return a python dictionary. For this though, you can't just plug it into a model. Create your own resource handler for your base type, which is capable of building your Model from a dict.

```
class ModelHandler(HandlerBase):
    allowed_methods = ('Get',)

    def read(self, request, id=None):
        if id is not None:
            m = Model.objects.get(id=id)

        ret = {}
        ret['field'] = m.field

        return ret
```

Comment: Yeah... I thought about this. But basically, that means I have to re-write the serialization myself !

Comment: @seb The classes you use can't be serialized conventially, by your own words. Therefore you have to do the serialization yourself. If you've got many different classes that need to be serialized the same way, have a BaseModelHandler that all your specific handlers derive from. Then you've captured the serialization in one place. You have to do it yourself, unless the django-ldapdb people have a serializer.